# RTE control unexpecting clears after switching to another tab Web Forms

Tags: webforms, syncfusion, rte

I am using the Syncfusion RichTextEditor on my Web Forms project and have trouble with unexpected clearing the data.

I initialize RTE control and other Web Forms controls in Page_Load method using the condition if (IsPostBack = true).

After I switch to another tab and IsPostBack = false the default Web Forms controls are initialized and have the values but Syncfusion RTE is empty.

The question is why the RTE doesn't save the data as another Web Froms Controls and what would be the solution?

Initializing:

[image]

Switching between pages (RTE is in the TableComments):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have validated your reported problem in EJ RTE control in Web Forms project. But we were unable to reproduce your reported problem in our end, the value of RTE maintained properly when switching the Tab. We have recorded video for your convenience, which can be downloaded from the below link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/305022/ze/RTE_Value-1627060724

We have also attached the sample for your convenience, please refer to the below link for sample application.

https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/305022/ze/RTE_Tab-226725218

Please check the above sample, if the issue still persists in your application. Please share some additional details it will be help us to provide you the prompt solution.

1. Share us the RTE rendering code block.
2. If you face any script error in console window of the browser, then please share us those error screenshots.
3. Share us the issue replicating sample or else replicate your reported issue in the shared sample.
4. Share us the screen recorded video with issue replicating steps.

We can also raise query in Syncfusion forums.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums

Regards,

Muthukrishnan K